# WP AJAX Request Not Working

Tags: functions, ajax

I'm trying to run `wp_insert_attachment` and `update_user_meta` using AJAX request but it doesn't work.

js file

```
import $ from "jquery";

class PersonalInfoUpdate {
  constructor() {
    this.events();
  }

  events() {
    document
      .getElementById("personalInfoUpdateForm")
      .addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        const updPerBtn = document.getElementById("updPerBtn");

        updPerBtn.innerHTML = `<div class="spinner-border text-light" role="status">
        <span class="sr-only">Updating...</span>
      </div>`;

        function getGender() {
          if (document.getElementById("male").checked == true) {
            return "male";
          } else {
            return "female";
          }
        }

        $.ajax({
          url: studymoreData.ajax_url,
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            action: "updateuserinfo",
            profilepicture: document
              .getElementById("imagePreview")
              .getAttribute("src"),
            sex: getGender(),
            dob: document.getElementById("dob").value,
            about: document.getElementById("about").value,
            security: studymoreData.user_update_nonce,
          },
          success: (response) => {
            if (response.updated == true) {
              console.log(response);
            } else {
              console.log(response);
            }
          },
          error: (response) => {
            console.log("Something went wrong");
            console.log(response);
          },
        });
        e.preventDefault();
      });
  }
}

export default PersonalInfoUpdate;
```

functions.php

```
function update_user_info()
{
  // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
  check_ajax_referer('user-update-nonce', 'security');

  // WordPress environment
  require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-load.php' );

  $wordpress_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  // $wordpress_upload_dir['path'] is the full server path to wp-content/uploads/2017/05, for multisite works good as well
  // $wordpress_upload_dir['url'] the absolute URL to the same folder, actually we do not need it, just to show the link to file
  $i = 1; // number of tries when the file with the same name is already exists

  $profilepicture = $_FILES['profilepicture'];
  $new_file_path = $wordpress_upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $profilepicture['name'];
  $new_file_mime = mime_content_type( $profilepicture['tmp_name'] );

  while( file_exists( $new_file_path ) ) {
    $i++;
    $new_file_path = $wordpress_upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $i . '_' . $profilepicture['name'];
  }

  // looks like everything is OK
  if( move_uploaded_file( $profilepicture['tmp_name'], $new_file_path ) ) {
    echo json_encode(array('updated'=>false, 'msg'=>'Uploadable', 'new_file_path'=>$new_file_path, 'profilepicture'=>$profilepicture, 'new_file_mime'=>$new_file_mime));

    $upload_id = wp_insert_attachment( array(
      'guid'           => $new_file_path, 
      'post_mime_type' => $new_file_mime,
      'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', $profilepicture['name'] ),
      'post_content'   => '',
      'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    ), $new_file_path );

    // wp_generate_attachment_metadata() won't work if you do not include this file
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

    // Generate and save the attachment metas into the database
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $upload_id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $upload_id, $new_file_path ) );
  }

  $currentUserId = get_current_user_id();

  $update_desc_status = update_user_meta($currentUserId, 'description', esc_attr($_POST['about']));
  if (!$update_desc_status) {
    echo json_encode(array('updated'=>false, 'message'=>__('Description could not be updated. update_desc_status: ' .$update_desc_status)));
  }

  $update_dob_status = update_user_meta($currentUserId, 'date_of_birth', esc_attr($_POST['dob']));
  if (!$update_dob_status) {
    echo json_encode(array('updated'=>false, 'message'=>__('Date of Birth could not be updated. update_dob_status: ' .$update_dob_status)));
  }

  $update_sex_status = update_user_meta($currentUserId, 'sex', esc_attr($_POST['sex']));
  if (!$update_sex_status) {
    echo json_encode(array('updated'=>false, 'message'=>__('Sex could not be updated. update_sex_status: ' .$update_sex_status)));
  }

  die();
}

function please_login() {
  echo json_encode(array('updated'=>false, 'message'=>__('You are not logged in')));
  die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_updateuserinfo', 'update_user_info');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_updateuserinfo', 'please_login');
```

I'm not very well familiar with the modern REST API endpoints, so I used this method. I get as return the error portion in the AJAX request ('Something went wrong').

Can anybody help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the old legacy Admin AJAX API to handle the requests rather than new modern REST API endpoints? Why does you Admin AJAX endpoint try to bootstrap WP from inside WP by loading `wp-load.php`? If it didn't do what you wanted, what did it do instead? How are you testing it? What's the response the JS recieves from the server? Please edit your question to answer all of those questions as best as you can, as well as any other debugging info you can have. As an aside, REST API endpoints tend to tell you in english what you did wrong in the response. Admin AJAX doesn't

Comment: @TomJNowell I tried the modern REST API but I was only able to update the value of description. I used `register_rest_field` to add 2 new rest fields (sex, date_of_birth), but they didn't show up. The site just refreshed automatically. Nothing else happened